# The Second part of my code isn't running and i'm new to using classes

Tags: c++, string, class

Hey the code is running fine without any errors but it just jumps to return 0.
I would also like to note that I'm kind of new to c++ and i just started using classes.

Thanks for the help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class List{
    public:
        void SetNote(string Note){
            Notepp = Note;
        }
        string getNotepp(){
            return Notepp;
        }
    private:
        string Notepp;
};


int main(){
    string x;
    cin >> x;

    List LisObj;
    LisObj.SetNote("Exit Notepad++.exe");
    if(LisObj.getNotepp() == x){
        cout << "Hello World\n";
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: What do you expect the program to do? You've told it to only print "Hello World" if the strings are the same - and clearly they will not be the same because you set `string Notepp`, and you don't set `string x` the same way.

Comment: What you mean 'jumps'?!

Comment: Well i just want the program to execute the code in the if statement if x is the same as Notepp. What i mean by jump i mean after "cin" after I enter the value of x it just ends the program it just "Jumps" to return 0;

Answer (score 2):

because you use "cin>>" to get a string!That is not possible,use "getline" instead,"cin" takes a blank to determine which part to get,for example:when you enter the sentence:"Exit Notepad++.exe",what your "x" get is just a "Exit",due to the blank after.The main function should be like this:

```
int main()
{
    string x;
    getline(cin,x);
    List LisObj;
    LisObj.SetNote("Exit Notepad++.exe");
    if(LisObj.getNotepp() == x)
    {
        cout << "Hello World\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print "hello world": You may do:

```
int main(){
    string x;
    cin >> x;

    List LisObj;
    LisObj.SetNote(x);
    if(LisObj.getNotepp() == x){
        cout << "Hello World\n";
    }

return 0;
}
```

Now if you want to print hello world only when user enters "Exit Notepad++.exe". Do not do like:

```
cin>>x;
```

as you input may contain space. Rather use `getline()` or `cin.getline()`

Answer (score 0):

When you input a string with spaces using `cin >>` when it reaches a space it will assume that it's the end of the input.

To get round this we use `getline()` or `cin.getline()`

Also instead of using `Return 0;` use :

```
cin.sync();
cin.ignore();
```

as in some cases `return 0;`

does not prevent the terminal from closing.